# add line-height option to ck editor in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

I am using ck-editor in drupal. So i just want to add line-height option on that. I don't know how to add line-height in ck-editor. Is there any way to add line-height in ck-editor.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to embed a style so that your content looks like `<p style="line-height:x;">content</p>`? Or do you want the content to have a bigger or smaller line height within the editor? Or do you want the line height to be present where you are showing the saved data outside CKE? A little more info plase :)

Comment: I think they mean having a menu item or properties dialog that allows one to change the line-height without modifying the HTML directly. Either by setting a pixel value or choosing from a set of predefined choices. I do not believe there is a way to do this with CKEditor -- at least I haven't found any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the same need for one of my project and then decided to create my own by referring some existing plugins.

Here is the link for ckeditor: 
http://ckeditor.com/addon/lineheight